# Strange router behavior in airodump

Tags: security, ubuntu-12.04, wpa2-psk, 802.11, aircrack-ng

While auditing the security of my wireless network I decided to take a peek at what airodump-ng could display.

This is what it outputs:

```
BSSID               PWR Beacons #Data #/s  CH   MB ENC CIPHER AUTH ESSID
xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   -85  0       52     0   123  -1 WPA              <LENGTH:0>
```

However if I look at my actual network through my computer's wireless network utility:

```
SSID: Virus Net
Channel: 6 
Network Type: Infrastructure 
Encryption: WPA(2)-PSK AES 
BSSID: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Not that I mind, but what's with the strange behavior in airodump? What does length:0 mean and how is my network on channel "123" with -1 MB?

Comment: I get this when the SSID is masked. Are you broadcasting the SSID or is the network meant to be 'hidden'? PS: the power level looks really low for decent capture

Comment: No, it's broadcasting. I'm not sure why airodump doesn't pick it up. As for the power level, it's suppose to be that way so people have a harder time getting in from outside my building.

Comment: have you used the --ignore-negative-one command?

Comment: --ignore-negative-one is not an option for airodump-ng.